# Получить массив в переменную php

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Здравствуйте. Задача следующая: В Базе есть ячейка с содержимым

```
[{"id":"1","value":"3"},{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"2"},{"id":"4","value":"3"},{"id":"13","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"14","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"15","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"16","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"17","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"18","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"19","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 3 \u043c\u0435\u0441\u044f\u0446\u0435\u0432"},{"id":"20","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 2 \u043d\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u044c"},{"id":"21","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"22","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"27","value":"\/images\/I9vh0kE3vkk.jpg"},{"id":"28","value":"123"},{"id":"29","value":"456"}]
```

Мне нужно получить самые последние значения 
`{"id":"28","value":"123"},{"id":"29","value":"456"}]`
Как можно реализовать данный функционал через, например, массив?
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В начале надо использовать **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**, затем отрезать с конца 2 элемента с помощью **[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)**:

```
$json = '[{"id":"1","value":"3"},{"id":"2","value":"2"},{"id":"3","value":"2"},{"id":"4","value":"3"},{"id":"13","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"14","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"15","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"16","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"17","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"18","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"19","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 3 \u043c\u0435\u0441\u044f\u0446\u0435\u0432"},{"id":"20","value":"\u041e\u0442 1 \u0434\u043e 2 \u043d\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u044c"},{"id":"21","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"22","value":"\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u043e"},{"id":"27","value":"\/images\/I9vh0kE3vkk.jpg"},{"id":"28","value":"123"},{"id":"29","value":"456"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);    
print_r(array_slice($arr, -2, 2, true));
```

Comment: Можете подсказать готовый код, который будет из последних двух (или по определенному id) элементов выводить значение,  если не сложно.

Comment: @Риад серьезно? а читать ответ ты не умеешь?

Comment: Изменил сообщение)

Comment: @Риад для новых вопросов есть кнопка [задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)